# Animacion en Samsungs

Tags: java, android, xml

Hola chicos y chicas (claro)

Tengo esta animation en mi proyecto

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<rotate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

y la establesco a un boton que puse en la barra de acciones

```
Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_around_center_point);
btnUpdate.startAnimation(rotate);
```

todo va como la ceda el boton rota en su centro
menos en los Samsungs que se desaparece y no exactamente en todos los modelos!
Que puede ser?

Comment: Reynaldo, se a lo que te refieres pero te aseguro que no sucede en todos, que sistema operativo tiene donde se presenta esto? podrías agregar una foto?

Comment: Yo manejo samsung y es cierto, la marca genera por defecto ciertos efectos a las app (android 7.0), este dilema se presenta en la gama alta tengo entendido, no he profundizado mas en el tema ...

Answer (score 0):

Hola intenta cambiar la animación así.

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btnUpdate,"rotation", 0f, 360f);
objectAnimator.setDuration(2000);
objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
objectAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
objectAnimator.start();
```

saludos

Comment: OK, voy a probar y posteare los resultados luego

Comment: Test 1: Se mueve igual en mi LG K10 .LOL. En cuanto pueda probar en el susodicho SamSung posteare

Comment: Probe en un S5 (SM-G900V) y no se arreglo la cosa, sigue sin mostrarse la animacion y por su puesto este se oculta al iniciar